# Do i need to make available source code of my SAAS if it uses GPLv3 library?

Tags: gpl

A developer built for me a SaaS for document analysis and one of the library used is GPLv3. The developer has shared source code with me as GPL. Now if i want to launch that SaaS for public consumption do I need to share publicly the source code i paid the developer for?

there are two usage scenarios.

1. user uploaded the file to our servers. I am assuming for this we don't have to share code as the code is not downloaded to user system.
2. user points the application to local file system and our system processes the content on client machine so the code calling the GPL code is downloaded on the system e.g. its in the browser/javascript. This is the scenario i am not sure about.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question from here and re-ask it on http://law.stackexchange.com/.  Despite the existence of some licensing questions on Software Engineering, they're generally off-topic here.

Comment: The developer himself could publish his code as GPL, and that license permits him to do so without your permission.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is not true at all. You don't have a right to publish source code that is written for hire without explicit permission, the default assumption is that code written for hire is exclusively licensed to the person that paid for it. GPL doesn't give you the right to publish source code, it says that if you do publish the binary then you must publish the source code. The developer most likely doesn't have permission to publish either.